# How to update the Primary key in my scenario:

Tags: sql, sqlite, primary-key, sql-update

I have three DB tables:

1) Details Table:

`_id | BirthDate | Name | isAdhoc | YearsOld | MonthsOld | WeeksOld | DaysOld | HoursOld | MinutesOld | SecondsOld|`

2) NotificationsTable:

`_id | NotificationFor | DateToNotify | IsExtraOrdinary | Notification Data | NotificationDateFor | TypeNotification | FriendsName | RadioType | PrimaryId`

3) NotificationsCron table:

`_id | NotificationFor | DateToNotify | IsExtraOrdinary | Notification Data | NotificationDateFor | TypeNotification | FriendsName | RadioType | PrimaryId`

The `_id` field in my table 1 (Details) is the PrimaryId field in my other two tables.

Table 2 (Notifications) and Table 3 (NotificationsCron) are identical. This is so because at midnight most of my records become obsolete, however there are certain couple of records which don't and I am interested in preserving them. So at the strike of 12 I copy these rows of interest and put them in the NotificationsCron table. Here the PrimaryID field is copied as well.

Following is what happens at midningt:

1) I copy the firlds of interest from Notifications to NotificationsCron.

2) I delete the Details table, I delete the notifications table.

3) I recalculate the values for everything and populate the Details table and the Notifications table again.

The catch here is that the PrimaryId field in my NotificationsCron table is that from the previous Details table, which no more exists as it was deleted and repopulated.

Now when I use a UNION query on Notifications Table and NotificationsCron table it might occur that the rows I am interested in exist in both the tables - a UNION all would have prevented that and I am using a UNION ALL clause however as the PrimaryID in both the tables is now different I get duplicates. Is there a way to overcome this, apart from introducing one more unique field in the Notifications Table and the NotificationsCron Table then I can query Details table based on Name and that unique field to check on the new _id and update it in the NotificationsCron table? Any hints?

Following is the Query I am using:

```
 "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Notifications UNION SELECT * FROM NotificationsCron) T ORDER BY SUBSTR(DATE('NOW'), 0)>SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0), SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0)";
```

After update process: 
NotificationsCron table:

[image]

Details Table:

[image]

NotificationsTable:

[image]

Comment: without examples this is a very obscure description

Comment: The process is huge, code examples wont be feasible here. But I will update my question with more details.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by overcoming this problem? You don't want to return rows from NotificationsCron table? You want to update NotificationsCron.PrimaryId so that it will be equal to _id in Details table? If so, is there a way for you to know that which new records are connected to the old records in NotificationsCron table?  I have some more questions in my mind as well :)

Comment: By overcoming this problem I mean that the primaryID field in Notifications and NotificationsCron table should be in sync. This should match the _id field in the Details table. The only way I see this can be done is that add one more unique column in the Notifications table and NotificationsCron table, like a DOB then I query the Details table with DOB and Name to fetch the _id field and update it in the NotificationsCron table.

Comment: I want to return rows from NotificationsCron table, if they are not duplicates of rows already in Notifications Table. However the PrimaryId mismatch defeats the purpose of my UNION query and it returns me duplicates because the PrimaryId does not match in case of duplicates now. Sure you can go ahead and shoot the questions.